# Is it possible to obtain the Request Object in a request scoped bean?

Tags: java, spring, request

I have a bean declared to be scope="request". is there a chance to obtain the request being used in that scope?

```
<bean class="FooRequestAware" scope="request"/>

class FooRequestAware {
      private final Request req;
      public final bar() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just autowire it

```
public class FooRequestAware {
      private @Autowired HttpServletRequest req;

      public final bar() {}
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
I've found this thread meanwhile:
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=76940